# Why can't we see who favored a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I would like to know why we can't see who favored a question? If the question is interesting, it would be great to see who favored this question to start some discussions.

Some question are really specialized and even if someone do not have an answer (so this person will not answer/comment the question since it's not a place for discussions), it would be nice to have the ability to share knowledge and assumptions somewhere else.

Comment: You can see the questions people favorited, so it doesn't seem to be a privacy issue.